# why is ajax and php script not posting back into original form

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I have this form and I'm using ajax to send data to a simple php script (just trouble shooting with simple php script) but it is not posting back data to original html form... here are the two scripts
contact.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Contact Us</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- stylesheet for this form -->
    <link href="contact-stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm()
        {
            var message = "";
            var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;    
            //do validation
            var jname = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
            var jemail = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
            var jsubject = document.forms["myForm"]["subject"].value;
            var jtext = document.forms["myForm"]["text"].value;
            var joutputMsg = "";

            //checking for empty fields
            if (jname == null || jname == "") {             
                message += "name field empty!\n";
            }               
            if (jname != "" && !jname.match(letters)) {
                message += "Invalid name: only letters allowed!\n";
            }
            if (jemail == null || jemail == "") {
                message += "email field is empty!\n";
            }
            if (jsubject == null || jsubject == "") {
                message += "Subject field is empty!\n";
            }
            if (jtext == null || jtext == "") {
                message += "Text field is empty!\n";
            }           

            if (message != "" ) {
                alert(message);
                return false;
            }

            //send data to php form--------------------->
            // create the XMLHttpRequest object, according browser          
            // create the variable that will contain the instance of the XMLHttpRequest object (initially with null value)
            var xmlHttp = null;

            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {     // for Forefox, IE7+, Opera, Safari, ...
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if(window.ActiveXObject) { // for Internet Explorer 5 or 6
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            // sends data to a php file, via POST, and displays the received answer         
            // create pairs index=value with data that must be sent to server
            var parameters="name="+jname+"&email="+jemail;

            request.open("POST", "contact.php", true);          // set the request

            // adds  a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.send(the_data);     // calls the send() method with datas as parameter

            // Check request status
            // If the response is received completely, will be transferred to the HTML tag with tagID
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                  document.getElementById("output-data").innerHTML = request.responseText;
                }
            }           
            return false;
        }       

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

      <div class="row">
          <div class="hero-unit" style="padding:20px 100px">
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            <p>aldkfjasdkfjaskdfasdfkasdkfjadsfjsdkfjaskfjasdkfjasjfaskdfjsdkfjsksdsdkjsd</p>       
        </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="my-form">
                <form class="form-horizontal" name="myForm" action="contact.php" onsubmit="return validateForm(event)" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Text:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <textarea name="text" class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="Text"></textarea>
              </div>    
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>    
            </div> 
        </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div style="width:500px;heigth:350px;border:solid 1px brown">
                <h1>GOOGLE MAP HERE!</h1>
              </div>
             <!-- <img sytle="padding:0px 20px" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Miami+Downtown,Miami,FL&zoom=13&size=500x350&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7CMiami+Downtown,Miami,FL">                     -->
          </div>      
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" id="msg-result" style="padding:10px 140px">
              <p id="output-data">

              </p>
            <!-- display form result message here! -->
      </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

contact.php

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];                  

    }

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }

    echo "Name: " . $name . "<br> Email: " . $email;    
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting response from your php script?

Comment: You actually have to return the data instead of just echoing it

Comment: change you php condition                                                                                                        if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'submit'){

Comment: @Bankzilla I believe echoing will work too.... Iam not sure coz iam more of a jquery ajax guy.. In my codes i echo the response which works just fine.

Comment: Also your php script has a few issues, the first `isset` doesn't have any reference to the variable `$email` as it's set later in the script. If either of the `isset` fail to run you will get undefined errors

Comment: @HarigovindR I stand corrected, appears you can use echo to return the data

Comment: Shouldn't contact.php be in quotes? (regarding `request.open("POST", contact.php, true);`)

Comment: Can we have the full code? there is so many errors in error I can only assume it's not the proper code. In validateForm, there is no reference to _email, subject, name, text_ also there is no variable called `the_data` which is being passed into the request. You also need to catch the action of the submitted form so you can run `event.preventDefault();` so it doesn't redirect to the contact form on submit. These are just the ones I've spotted

Comment: still I'm getting error ReferenceError: request is not defined. here's the part of the code the console is pointing at: request.open("POST", "contact.php", true); // set the reques. Does the php page needs to have a return statement instead of a echo. because I'm still posting to another page. I've seen examples out there where ppl have echo in their php page.

Comment: take a look at the code above, I have updated the changes I made in my code

Answer (score 0):

There is so many errors but I've got it working, you might want to look at the naming convention on your input fields. For example on *name* you have the id of `id="inputEmail13"`. Use the browser console to see error messages as you're developing.

```
function validateForm(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var message = "";
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;    
    //do validation
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var subject = document.forms["myForm"]["subject"].value;
    var text = document.forms["myForm"]["text"].value;
    var outputMsg = "";

    //checking for empty fields
    if (name == null || name == "") {               
        message += "name field empty!\n";
    }               
    if (name != "" && !name.match(letters)) {
        message += "Invalid name: only letters allowed!\n";
    }
    if (email == null || email == "") {
        message += "email field is empty!\n";
    }
    if (subject == null || subject == "") {
        message += "Subject field is empty!\n";
    }
    if (text == null || text == "") {
        message += "Text field is empty!\n";
    }           

    if (message != "" ) {
        alert(message);
        return false;
    }

    //send data to php form--------------------->
    // create the XMLHttpRequest object, according browser          
    // create the variable that will contain the instance of the XMLHttpRequest object (initially with null value)
    var xmlHttp = null;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {     // for Forefox, IE7+, Opera, Safari, ...
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) { // for Internet Explorer 5 or 6
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    // sends data to a php file, via POST, and displays the received answer         
    // create pairs index=value with data that must be sent to server
    var parameters="name="+name+"&email="+email;

    xmlHttp.open("POST", "contact.php", true);            // set the request

    // adds  a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.send(parameters);     // calls the send() method with datas as parameter

    // Check request status
    // If the response is received completely, will be transferred to the HTML tag with tagID
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
          document.getElementById("output-data").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }           
    return false;
}
```

In the html you want to remove the `visibility:hidden;` on the output div

```
<div class="col-sm-6" id="msg-result" style="padding:10px 140px;">
      <p id="output-data">
      </p>
    <!-- display form result message here! -->
</div>
```

Edit:

Cause of the request is undefined is because you're never creating a variable called request, yet you're calling one.

```
request.open("POST", "contact.php", true);
```

This line will throw the first error saying it's undefined, this can be fixed easily by changing `request` to `xmlHttp` or modifying `xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();` to be `request = new ....` same should be done to the other xmlHttp assignment.

Comment: regarding the id, I don't see how that is impacting the fact that is not posting back to original page. However, I made the modifications recommended, but still I'm getting error ReferenceError: request is not defined. here's the part of the code the console is pointing at:    request.open("POST", "contact.php", true);   // set the request

Comment: take a look at the code above, I updated the changes, but still not working

Comment: It's because you have no variable named _request_, if you look at my code I changed everywhere that _request_ is mentioned with _xmlHttp_, as that's what you've called the http request variable.